# Is there a podcasts player which remembers the time?

Tags: podcast

I tried out many different programs like gPodder, Rhythmbox and Banshee, but with none, the program remembers the played time.

Is there a player which can do that and download automatically the newest podcasts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest **Miro** which you can get from the software centre.

It can play both video and audio podcast's and remembers the where you stopped and will start again from that position.

[image: Miro podcast player]

as you can see the bottom podcast was stopped at 17:14 if I start it again it will resume from that point.

Comment: May I ask how you made your windows look so beautiful?^^

Comment: that would be a theme from tiheum the same designer behind the faenza icons pack the theme is here | http://tiheum.deviantart.com/gallery/#/d3d0w1u | however it was designed for gnome2 and I don't know if it will be ported to gnome3